# python automatically create parameters in a lambda function

Tags: python

```py
constraint_condition = [lambda x: [x[0], x[1]]]
mid.gen_answer(constraint_ueq)
```

In codes above, `mid` is a class, and the method `gen_answer` is calling a function from another python package which requires n-dimension input written in this format：
`lambda x:[x[0],x[1],...x[n]]`

How do I create lambda function and fill these paramters automatically? For example I want a 4-dimension input, I shall be writing this by my hand like this:
`lambda x:[x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3]]`, but what if there are more dimensions(like 12)? There is a way to let python write these (`x[1],x[2]...`) for me?

Comment: is `len(x) == n`?

Comment: `lambda x: [sub_x for sub_x in x]`?

Comment: to add to @jfaccioni one liner, if you want less indexes than whole length of x, you can do `in x[:k]` where k is the number of dims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guy, I solved this by using `lambda x:[sub_x for sub_x in x[:n]]`. Thx for your help